# Привязка ScrollView к superView storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

я столкнулся с проблемой и мне нужна помощь. Мне нужно scrollView привязать к superView.
Структура такая:
1. ScrollView привязан к superView сториборда
2. в ScrollView находится view, который привязан к superView ScrollView
3. на симуляторах ScrollView находится где нужно, а вот view, с отступом, как будто привязан к safe area

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее в результате должно было получиться, что синий элемент view должен покрывать всю область statusBar'a
Я не могу разобраться почему, я создал тестовый проект с демонстрацией этой проблемы, подскажите что я не так делаю?

Проект: https://github.com/Constantine1995/TestScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Решило проблему  scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

Comment: Будьте добры, отметьте ваш ответ как решение проблемы

Comment: "Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 10 часов"